# PHP duplicates in nested multidimensional array to combine certain value

Tags: php, arrays, nested-loops

The desired output is to have:

> {"userId":1,"email":"example@email.com","first":"Tyler","last":"Kanz","groups":[{"groupId":"1","groupName":"GROUP A","groupRoles":["1", "3"]},{"groupId":"2","groupName":"GROUP B","groupRoles":["2"]}]}

Which would compare the Group IDs and combine duplicates with their Group Roles.
I have tried using,

```
foreach ($groups as $group) {
    if ($group['groupId'] == $group_id) {
        array_push($group['groupRoles'], $group_role);
        //And then unsetting the array
    }
```

It is just adding all of the Groups/Roles into the Group array onto the Groups Array.

> array(3) { ["groupId"]=> string(1) "1" ["groupName"]=> string(5)
> "GROUP A" ["groupRoles"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } } array(3) {
> ["groupId"]=> string(1) "2" ["groupName"]=> string(10) "GROUP B"
> ["groupRoles"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" } } array(3) {
> ["groupId"]=> string(1) "1" ["groupName"]=> string(5) "GROUP A"
> ["groupRoles"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "3" } }
> {"userId":1,"email":"example@email.com","first":"Tyler","last":"Kanz","groups":[{"groupId":"1","groupName":"IRISS","groupRoles":["1"]},{"groupId":"2","groupName":"GROUP B","groupRoles":["2"]},{"groupId":"1","groupName":"GROUP A","groupRoles":["3"]}]}

```
 foreach ($groupmeta as $value) {
        $group_roles = array();
        $array = unserialize($value['property_value']);
        
        if ($array[0] == $user_ID) {
            //Gets Group ID and Role
            $group_id = $value['group_id'];

            $group_role = $array[1];
            $exists = false;
            
            $group_name_q= json_decode(json_encode($wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare('SELECT group_name FROM groups WHERE id=%s', $group_id))), true);
            $group_name = $group_name_q[0]['group_name'];

            echo $group_role;
            echo '<br>';
        
            $group_roles[] = $group_role;
            $group_info = array(
                'groupId'=>$group_id,
                'groupName'=>$group_name,
                'groupRoles'=>$group_roles,
            );
            $groups[] = $group_info;

        }
    }
    $sorted_groups = array();
        
        echo '<br>';
    }

    $return_arr = array(
        "userId"=>$user_ID, 
        "email"=>$user_email, 
        "first"=>$user_first, 
        "last"=>$user_last, 
        "groups"=>$groups
    );

    echo json_encode($return_arr);
    //var_dump($groupmeta_value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer, FOREACH runs as a cloned object.
Instead I used the following FOR loop and got the desired results.

```
                $found_group = false;
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($groups); $i++) {
                if ($groups[$i]['groupId'] == $group_id) {
                    array_push($groups[$i]['groupRoles'], $group_role);
                    $found_group = true;
                }

        }
            if (!$found_group) {
                //Group Name
            $group_name_q= json_decode(json_encode($wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare('SELECT group_name FROM groups WHERE id=%s', $group_id))), true);
            $group_name = $group_name_q[0]['group_name'];
                $group_roles[] = $group_role;
            $group_info = array(
                'groupId'=>$group_id,
                'groupName'=>$group_name,
                'groupRoles'=>$group_roles,
            );
            $groups[] = $group_info;
            }
```